# Pass parameter name and its value from specflow Examples Table as key and value pairs to specflow method

Tags: specflow

My requirement is to set headers for an HttpRequest.

My scenario is as below :

`And I have the headers comprising <clientId> and <clientSecret> and <Authorization>`

`Examples:
|clientId | ClientSecret | Authorization |
|123      |  mySecret    | MyAuthority   |`

`[Given(@"I have the 3 authorisation headers comprising (.*) and (.*) and (.*)")]`

`public void SetHeaders(string one,string two, string three)
{
}`

In above method I want to create a dictionary of parameter name and its argument value like ClientID:123, ClientSecret:mySecret. Please note that I am talking about examples table and not table for individual step.

Work Around for this approach are as below:

I can pass these values as comma separated text string arguments in strict sequence and map them with correct parameter name.In this case I am required to be extra careful to pass parameters in strict sequence. Also I can create three different step definitions and pass one parameter at each time.

I want to avoid all above and pass only parameter names required to be set with their respective argument values to a method which sets headers for my HttpWebRequest.

Comment: You should put the code inside the question, not as a link. You cannot use examples for that: this will result in a test for each row, not one test using all the settings. Show us the complete Specflow example that you want to implement.  One way to do this is implementing this in a single background step.